# App crashes logging "warning: could not load any Objective-C class information."

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, block

I am using Afnetworking version 3.0 and trying to load some data. The data is coming in the response object properly and I am trying to parse that in an `NSMutableArray`. However this is crashing giving me error-

> "warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available."

My Data Parsing class is following-

**DataProcessing.h-**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Book.h"
#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h>
#import <MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h>

@interface DataProcessing : NSObject

-(void)getAllTheBooks;

-(void)setBookList:(NSMutableArray*)list;
-(NSMutableArray*)getBookList;

@end
```

**DataProcessing.m:**

```
#import "DataProcessing.h"

@interface DataProcessing(){
    Book *individualBook;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *bookList;
@property(nonatomic, strong) BookDetails *bookDetails;

@end
@implementation DataProcessing

-(void)getAllTheBooks{

   NSMutableArray  *bookList =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"https://natasha....../items" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSArray *bookCollectionArray = (NSArray*)responseObject;

    for (NSDictionary *dict in bookCollectionArray) {
        individualBook = [[Book alloc]init];
        individualBook.bookID = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
        individualBook.bookLink = [dict objectForKey:@"link"];
        individualBook.bookTitle = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

        [bookList addObject:individualBook];
    }
    [self setBookList:bookList];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}

-(void)setBookList:(NSMutableArray*)list{
    self.bookList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.bookList = list;
}
-(NSMutableArray*)getBookList{
    return self.bookList;
}
@end
```

My Controller's `viewDidLoad` is as following-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DataProcessing *processing = [[DataProcessing alloc]init];
    [processing getAllTheBooks];
    NSMutableArray *array = [processing getBookList];
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
}
```

When it crashes, it shows something like this -

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not 100% sure this would work but you could try initializing the mutable array in an init method, then just have the self.bookList = list; inside the setter method.

Comment: Ah well, regardless there is no need to keep re initializing the bookList property inside of a method that will continuously be called. That only needs to happen once where the class is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to allocate a new NSMutableArray inside of the bookList property's setter method, assign it to the bookList property, and then set it to the list being passed in. Instead of accessing the bookList property using `self` inside of the accessor methods it is advised to use the **backing variable** or **ivar** (instance variable) instead, which is prefixed by an underscore (e.g. `_bookList`) and known as **direct access**.

The reason you should use **direct access** instead of `self.bookList` is because `self.bookList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` is translated to `[self setBookList:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];`, which means that inside of your setter method for the `bookList` property you will be calling the setter method again and causing a recursive loop. For example, the code you have as of now will translate in to something like the following:

```
-(void)setBookList:(NSMutableArray*)list{
    [_bookList release];
    [self setBookList:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
    [self setBookList:list];
    [_bookList retain];
}
```

Thus, on the second call to `setBookList:`, you're trying to release the bookList property after you have already released it, which is why you're getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. If you're not doing any type of validation or in need of custom code inside of the setter method you do not have to define it as the setter method will be automatically defined for you. However, for reference, below is the proper way to define your setter method without any modification (in compliance with the aforementioned and ARC):

```
- (void)setBookList:(NSMutableArray *)bookList
{
    if (_bookList != bookList)
        _bookList = bookList;
}
```